# Import tensorflow contrib module is slow in tensorflow 1.2.1

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

Is there a reason for the tensorflow contrib module imports being slower in 1.2.1 than 1.1.0? I am using Python 3.5.

The overhead is not significant using the command-line, its perhaps around 2-3 seconds. However in an IDE, it becomes quite significant (~ 10 seconds to import tensorflow.contrib as opposed to (~0.5 seconds) in tensorflow 1.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is slow to import because it is doing `inspect.stack()` many times, which take a lot of time each time. I have reported [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11829), and have submitted a PR with a fix.