# What can cause the tensorflow import to be so slow?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, import

I've been using tensorflow for quite some time. Recently my scripts run very slow (> 80 sec) as to earlier (< 1 sec). I narrowed the issue down to `import tensorflow`, which alone is taking all the time (all other libs and ops are running << 1 sec).

I might have a trace, but I don't know what to do with it: When I keyboard-interrupt (Strg+C) the execution during the 80 sec import, usually this is what comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../py_env/tf_unet/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "/.../py_env/tf_unet/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 694, in main
    execsitecustomize()
  File "/.../py_env/tf_unet/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 548, in execsitecustomize
    import sitecustomize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sitecustomize.py", line 3, in <module>
    import apport_python_hook
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 896, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1139, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1113, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1225, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1264, in _fill_cache
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Does this mean, something with "filling the caches" (`_fill_cache`) is wrong? Anyone experience with this? Can I fix this somehow?

---

What I've tried so far:

I broke down `import tensorflow` to only modules I need (`from tensorflow import train` / `python_io` / `compat`), with no improvement.

I found other people complaining about long `import tensorflow` speed [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/930), [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11829) and in the [corresponding SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093653/import-tensorflow-contrib-module-is-slow-in-tensorflow-1-2-1), but in the range of < 10 sec and referring to specific modules (`tf.contrib` or `tf.learn`). So not much to learn from there. Also I am using `tensorflow 1.4.0` which apparently fixed the problems described there.

Just for reference, I am using this little piece of code to determine the speed:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
print('import tensorflow')
start = timer()
import tensorflow
end = timer()
print('Elapsed time: ' + str(end - start))
```

Comment: In my case I had serious slowness due to the fact that I had my TF virtual environment on a network drive. Moving it to local helped, not sure if that applies in your case.

Comment: @mikkola: I didn't consider this option since I'm working on a cluster with distributed storage anyways. However we do have different raids and it turns out that one is running at the edge. Moving the tensorflow installation to a different raid actually hugely improved performance (import now @ 5-15 sec). Thanks! You want to turn that to an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not the only reason that can cause this, but in my experience certainly plays a role. I had serious slowness in importing Tensorflow due to the fact that I had my TF virtual environment on a network drive. Moving the virtual environment to a local hard drive helped quite a bit in this respect.

You could try doing something similar that applies in your environment.