# Tensorflow import takes too long

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have installed tensorflow-cpu and it takes around 5 seconds to import.

Command used to install tensorflow:

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

I have found other related articles on stackoverflow and github but none of them seems to help.

Note: I am using intel i7 8th gen with windows.

Comment: is 5 seconds a long time in python?

Comment: Have you eliminated other potential influences, like other programs running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

5 seconds is about the time the import needs on my system as well.

If you are interested in specifics, you can use

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('import tensorflow')
```

to profile the call.

Related: [import tensorflow is very slow?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37729), [What can cause the tensorflow import to be so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053434/what-can-cause-the-tensorflow-import-to-be-so-slow), [How to speed up `import tensorflow`?](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/discuss/c/nWxP-prgWpY?pli=1)(Older)

Comment: Compared to pytorch which takes less than a second, 5 secs is too much. As you can see in the github link that other people are facing the same issue as well.

Comment: I agree that the difference between pytorch and tensorflow seems to be a lot, however the times described in the posts seem to be in accordance with what i am benchmarking. The long import time of tensorflow doesn't seem to be an "error" though